# Keycloak Admin Console Page is Empty

Tags: keycloak

I am getting empty page after updating a **Frontend URL** for the default **Master Realm**. Below is the screenshot of the realm settings. I am using Keycloak 18.0.0 version.

[image]

Can anyone please help me out

Comment: Did you have a look at the network browser tab to see if you get any error responses ?

Comment: No error response in console after saving the changes

Comment: Did you set it to a valid URL?

Comment: Yes. I set it to a local URL http://localhost:3000